# Angular no me muestra los datos actualizados

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

Estoy armando una aplicacion con Angular y Ionic 5 donde se pueden agregar 'Deudas' y las deudas se muestran en una lista. Tengo un componente donde las muestra y otro componente donde creo la deuda. Cuando Creo la deuda me vuelve a enviar a la lista para poder verla.

Cuando yo entro al componente lista-deudas esta vacio como debe ser, cuando me dirijo al componente para crear una deuda y vuelvo de nuevo a la lista-deudas para ver mi deuda que cree... me la muestra pero yo tengo en mi lista-deudas un arreglo donde tengo las deudas. Cuando yo quiero sacar la cantidad de deudas de ese arreglo me muestra que es 0, incluso cuando me esta mostrando una deuda en pantalla.

En esta primera imagen, no hay deudas. Por lo tanto voy a crear una deuda con el boton flotante de abajo a la derecha
[image]

Ahora cree una deuda y se muestra en la lista, pero en la consola me dice que del arreglo de 'Cobrar' hay 0 elementos y incluso en la posicion 0 no hay ningun objeto. Pero si toco el boton azul 'Mostrar' que me muestra el arreglo Cobrar y el Pagar me dice que hay un objeto en cobrar, que es la deuda que me muestra
[image]

No entiendo porque pasa esto, tiene algo que ver con los ¿ciclos de vida de los componentes?

**Editado**

Cambie el codigo y ahora me muestra la longitud pero con un elemento menos al que realmente tiene. Si el arreglo tiene 1 elemento, muestra 0. Si tiene 2 elementos muestra 1.

Agregue una deuda en cobrar y el objeto esta dentro del arreglo this.porCobrar y me dice que la longitud es 0
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Este es el servicio donde creo la deuda.**

```
export class DeudaService {

  porPagar: Deuda [] = [];
  porCobrar: Deuda [] = [];

  deudaTemp: Deuda = {
    Tipo: 'Pagar',
    id: '',
    Nombre: '',
    Monto: 0,
    FechaCreada: null,
    Completada: false,
    FechaFinalizada: false,
    AvatarPath: '',
  };

  constructor() {
    // this.deudaTempDefault();

  }

  crearDeuda(tipo: string , nombre: string, monto: number, sexo: string) {

    this.deudaTemp.Nombre = nombre;
    this.deudaTemp.Monto = monto;
    this.deudaTemp.id = uuid();
    this.deudaTemp.FechaCreada = new Date().getDate();
    this.deudaTemp.FechaFinalizada = false;
    this.deudaTemp.AvatarPath = this.asignarAvatar(sexo);

    if (tipo === 'pagar') {
      this.deudaTemp.Tipo = 'Pagar';
      this.porPagar.push(this.deudaTemp);

      // this.deudaTempDefault();

      return;
    }

    if (tipo === 'cobrar') {
      this.deudaTemp.Tipo = 'Cobrar';
      this.porCobrar.push(this.deudaTemp);

      // this.deudaTempDefault();

      return;
    } else {

      console.log('El tipo de this.deudaTemp no es Valido', this.deudaTemp);
      return;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor el problema que tienes? No me queda claro.

Comment: El problema es que (en la segunda imagen) en la consola muestra 'PorCobrar 0 undefined' como si el arreglo no tuviera elementos. Pero en la pagina me lo esta mostrando, esta mostrando un objeto que acabo de crear.

Comment: Si no entiendo mal, lo que quieres es que te muestre Pagar? Podrías adjuntar el servicio?

Comment: Pon todo el código ahí en consola hay una linea 49 y no la veo.

Comment: Y por lo que veo de tu código primero estas llamando el método donde se imprime por cobrar antes de que entre tu arreglo de deudas por eso marca undefined por que no existe a simple deducción mía.

Comment: Parte del problema era lo que dijo @AlexisNarvaez ahora tengo otro distinto en que la longitud del arreglo es menor a la que realmente es. Ahi actualice el post mejor explicado y con el servicio que uso.

Comment: Hola Fonzii, creo que no marca la longitud exacta por los returns que tienes...trata de quitarlos a ver sucede juega a prueba y error.

Comment: Tienes 2 if, trata de usar el primer if y luego else if para que tu código se vea mas limpio y quita los return a ver si es eso.